# Querying an OWL ontology

Tags: javascript, rdf, owl

In an OWL ontology, we have to link classes with a certain integer.
For example, we have a LWM2MTemperatureObject class which has always an objectID of 3303.
(we're modelling a subset of the [LwM2M specifications](https://www.omaspecworks.org/what-is-oma-specworks/iot/lightweight-m2m-lwm2m/)
where we describe which connections there are between objects and resources).
The [LwM2M ontology](https://iotsolidugent.inrupt.net/public/ontologies/omalwm2m.owl.ttl) is edited using [Protégé](https://protege.stanford.edu/).
We accomplish the linking by having a `Subclass of` set to `'hasObjectID' value 3303`.

Question 1&2 are used for better understanding, question 3 is what we want to accomplish.

Question 1) According to my understanding, this means if we say in RDF (using Turtle):

```
:mySensor a lwm2m:LWM2MTemperatureObject
```

That we can automatically infer that `:mySensor lwm2m:hasObjectID 3303`, right?

Question 2) If we say:

```
:myOtherSensor lwm2m:hasObjectID 3303
```

then we can infer that `:myOtherSensor a lwm2m:LWM2MTemperatureObject`, **if** it also conforms to the other restrictions imposed by `Subclass of`. (right?)

Question 3)

In a javascript application, we want to discover to which class a certain Subject (`:mySensor2`) belongs by using the linked ID (3303).
For the moment, we use the fact that our OWL ontology is serialized in turtle format and looks like this:
[figure: subset from our ontology visualized in RDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wks6K.png)

We use an exact SPARQL query on the RDF structure of our OWL ontology.

```
        PREFIX lwm2m: <${ontology}>
        PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
        PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
        PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
        PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 
        SELECT ?objectName
        WHERE
                {
                        ?objectName rdfs:subClassOf lwm2m:Object, ?blank .
                        ?blank owl:onProperty lwm2m:hasObjectID ;
                                owl:hasValue "3303"^^xsd:integer .
                }
```

With this query, we then get the class we want.

This of course depends on the fact that we use Turtle syntax to store our ontology.

The question is: how should this be done without depending <s>on the syntax</s> on the storage format, preferably using a Javascript library.
(We found a reasoner in Javascript [HyLAR](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hylar#supported-inferences)<s>, but how should we proceed?</s>)

**Edit:**
We could for example store the ontology as OWL/XML syntax and then our approach of 'loading the ontology as an RDF graph' will not work without further work.
Since seeing

> Each OWL 2 ontology represented as an instance of this conceptual
>   structure can be converted into an RDF graph [OWL 2 RDF Mapping];

([OWL 2 syntax reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Introduction)) I think this might just be a technical problem.

Thus, all OWL ontologies can converted to RDF.

Rephrasing question 3)
it's not bad to explicitly query on the fact that our ontology has in RDF a structure ([visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUeGr.png)) like (?):
class --> blank node --> 3303

Or which other method should we use to find the class?

Thanks in advance for any help!
Let me know if any information has to be added.

Info:

Used turtle prefixes:

```
@prefix : <http://example.com/deviceWithSensors#>
@prefix lwm2m: <https://iotsolidugent.inrupt.net/public/ontologies/omalwm2m.owl.ttl#>
```

Comment: 1.) yes 2) no, `SubClassOf` is not enough, it's always "from left to right" resp. "if ... then" - for your case, you need `EquivalentTo` 3.) not sure what you mean by "without depending on the syntax"

Comment: @UninformedUser Thanks for your reply. I updated my question, but if it doesn't get answered it's not a huge problem.
Our university project (involving OWL and RDF) is actually finished, but this question is for future work/reference.